# Error: list index out of range - CustomTkinter App

Tags: python, list, methods, customtkinter

I am very new with python, I've been now creating my own project as I believe is the only way to learn faster. I am working in a project that should use 5 formulas to calculate an output. To do that I created a list with the numbers should be used in the formula, the other empty list will be updated as soon as the user select the values throught the radio buttons. The thing is when I press the calculate button to run the calculate method it trigged Error:list index out of range.  I don't know why but I've been trying to solve it many times, Also I am learning little bit more about class, methods and attributes. Part of the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


CONSTANT_1 = 10  # Constant value when iCruise is 4 in size
CONSTANT_2 = 240  # Constant value when iCruise is 4 in size and X model
CONSTANT_3 = 280  # Constant value when iCruise is 6 in size and x model, also iCruise 6 with different steering head
CONSTANT_4 = 55  # Constant value when iCruise is 6 / 8 / 9 standard


class App:
    def __init__(self, master: ctk.CTk):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("490x520")
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        self.master.wm_title("iCruise TF Offset App")

        # variable number 
        self.list = [CONSTANT_1, CONSTANT_2, CONSTANT_3, CONSTANT_4]

        self.list2 = []

............
        def selection(self):
            if self.radio_var1.get() == 1 and self.radio_var3.get() == 1:
                # Condition to use iCruise 4 3/4" - Standard
                self.list2 = self.list.append(CONSTANT_1)
            elif self.radio_var1.get() == 1 and self.radio_var3.get() == 2:
                # Condition to use iCruise 4 3/4" - X
                self.list2 = self.list.append(CONSTANT_2)
            elif (
                self.radio_var1.get() == 2
                and self.radio_var2.get() == 2
                and self.radio_var3.get() == 1
            ):
                # Condition to use iCruise 6 3/4" - Steering Head M2M
                self.list2 = self.list.append(CONSTANT_3)

            elif (
                self.radio_var1.get() == 1
                and self.radio_var2.get() == 2
                and self.radio_var3.get() == 1
            ):
                # Condition to use iCruise 6 3/4" - Steering Head TVR
                self.list2 = self.list.append(CONSTANT_3)
            elif (
                self.radio_var1.get() == 1
                and self.radio_var2.get() == 1
                and self.radio_var3.get() == 1



    def calculate(self):
        try:
            a = float(self.gtf_entry.get())
            b = float(self.cd_entry.get())
            c = self.list2[0]
            tool_face = round((c - a + b), 2)
            if tool_face < 0:
                tool_face += 360
                print(tool_face)
            else:
                print(tool_face)
```

I tried to used the append method to update my new list, however it shows Error: List index out of range.

Comment: self.list2[0] will raise IndexError if self.list2 is empty - i.e., len(self.list2) == 0

Answer (score -1):

### Issue Explanation

The issue in your code is related to how you are using the `append` method with the `self.list2` attribute. The `append` method modifies the list in place and returns `None`. So, when you do `self.list2 = self.list.append(CONSTANT_1)`, `self.list2` becomes `None`, causing the `List index out of range` error in the `calculate` method when you try to access `self.list2[0]`.

### Solution

To fix this issue, you should use `self.list.append(CONSTANT_1)` without assigning it to `self.list2`. Also, make sure that you update the other parts of your code where you are using `self.list2` accordingly.

Here's the modified `selection` method:

```py
def selection(self):
    if self.radio_var1.get() == 1 and self.radio_var3.get() == 1:
        # Condition to use iCruise 4 3/4" - Standard
        self.list.append(CONSTANT_1)
    elif self.radio_var1.get() == 1 and self.radio_var3.get() == 2:
        # Condition to use iCruise 4 3/4" - X
        self.list.append(CONSTANT_2)
    elif (
        self.radio_var1.get() == 2
        and self.radio_var2.get() == 2
        and self.radio_var3.get() == 1
    ):
        # Condition to use iCruise 6 3/4" - Steering Head M2M
        self.list.append(CONSTANT_3)
    elif (
        self.radio_var1.get() == 1
        and self.radio_var2.get() == 2
        and self.radio_var3.get() == 1
    ):
        # Condition to use iCruise 6 3/4" - Steering Head TVR
        self.list.append(CONSTANT_3)
    elif (
        self.radio_var1.get() == 1
        and self.radio_var2.get() == 1
        and self.radio_var3.get() == 1
    ):
        # Add more conditions if needed
        pass
```

I got this information from various sources on the web, mainly from the [CTk Docs](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/)